# date + time to timestamp in angular2

Tags: angular, timestamp, primeng

I want to make a Google Calendar-like scheduler app.

I decided to use PrimeNG. The output format of the calendar is

```
2016-01-16T16:00:00
```

The API I want to interact with uses timeStamp.

I tried to make a JavaScript function to prase my date format:

```
function toTimestamp(strDate){
   var datum = Date.parse(strDate);
   return datum/1000;
}
alert(toTimestamp('02/13/2009 23:31:30'));
```

But my problem is that I can't use the format of PrimeNG.

How can I interact correctly with the format I need to convert to a timestamp?

Otherwise, how I can get this date format (`2016-01-16T16:00:00`) to a timestamp using Angular 2?

Comment: Check out `date` pipe, you can manipulate with dates and time using this pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use plain javascript:

```
let time = new Date("2016-01-16T16:00:00");
alert(time.getTime());
```

This will return you a timestamp. Just be aware of timezones.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to get the desired timestamp.

eg: `moment("2016-01-16T16:00:00").format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss")`

The output will be:

"01/16/2016 16:00:00"

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path as far as i can see.
I suggest you use the Javascript Date https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
to create a new Date instead of trying to parse the raw output of primeng.

`new Date()` can be use with a multitude of parameters.
If `new Date(datestring)` is not working out as I would expect, use split to split your output string into variables that u can use to fill

`new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);`

This might be a little bit of sweat work but it should do the trick.

This is my first answer so please mods be gentle with my formatting.