# Want to build an attendance management system using MEAN stack

Tags: mean-stack

I want to build an attendance management system using MEAN stack. The application should work like this -

There will be an admin who will control CRUD operations on User and as well as look into the Attendance of each user and have a detailed list of average attendance of the user per month and per year.

There will be a user page and when the user logs in i want to store the date and time in the client side and then send it to the database. So that based on the time and date the admin can see when the user has logged in and mark the user as present for that particular day.

I want to know how to store the date and time in the client side and then pass it onto the database for calculations. Also wanted to know that is it necessary to authenticate in the front end as well?

Comment: I have tried to answer your query, but your question seems quite broad. Do you know how to perform CRUD operations in MEAN stack? If yes, then It should not be a big problem to get time and save it in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be I am late, but I can try to answer your query. 
You can store date and time as an object and pass it via request parameters to the backend to store it in the database. 
You can take a look a the following on how to get date and time in Javascript [How do I get the time of day in javascript/Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775904/date-time-to-timestamp-in-angular2)